# Exchange data between nodes in OMNeT++

Tags: networking, omnet++

I'm using OMNeT++ to simulate a network. The messages exchanged between nodes are type integer and complex number.

How can I exchange the type of data between different nodes, because cMessage cannot accept integer and complex data.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily define custom messages with any content using `.msg` files. Take a look at the [corresponding chapter in the Simulation Manual](https://www.omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#cha:msg-def).
This way you can define your "complex" type message, by adding two fields of type `double`, named for example `re` and `im`.
The message compiler will generate a subclass of `cMessage` from this definition, which you can use for communication between nodes.

Comment: Thanks you very.Please can you explain me more and give me a simple example please.