# operation and exchange complex number data in omnet++

Tags: omnet++

I want to add a complex number data field in messages.msg in omnet ++ in order to do operations in complex number node I think that it dont accept complex number 
Shoulf I add it as a struct ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of adding a complex number to a message:

1. As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50814209/4653172) one can just add two fields to a message, for example:

   ```
   message MyMessage {
       double re;
       double im;
   };
   ```
2. Using a new C++ structure, for example:

   ```
   cplusplus {{
   struct ComplexNumber {
       double re;
       double im;
   };
   }}

   class noncobject ComplexNumber;

   message MyMessage {
       ComplexNumber complex;
   };
   ```

Comment: Please I have another problem my class complex using template when I define as as a type in a field in .msf file  it  gives me error in géneration messages.cc and  messages_m.h messages_m.cc  the error Description Resource Path Location Type
syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting ';' or '=' messages.msg C/C++ Problem